# Batch Script to Monitor and Kill Application

Tags: function, batch-file, kill

Hello and thank you for taking the time to look at my question. I come from the Linux environment and familiar with BASH but not so much with batch language.

**Overview:**
I am doing some experiments on SSD for life expectancy for NAND. I am running an IOMeter application to "age" the drive and then checking the life left on a drive. In an admin PowerShell window or command prompt, I have a cmd line tool in which I can retrieve the percentage. I would like to log the output of the percentage every 10 min and "watch" for the counter to hit 90%. Once it hits 90% kill IOmeter app. I will have multiple drive, but which every hits 90% kill IOMeter.

**Flow:**

1. Manually start IO with IOmeter (Multiple Workers) (windows app) -->
2. Open Administrator cmd Window.-->
3. Run command to retrieve (ie. .*/smartmon getsmart all | Select-String
   -Pattern 'Percentage used'*) -->
4. Pipe that data to a text file every 10 min (below is the output) -->
5. Watch the counter until it hit 90% and
6. Finally kill the IOMeter App.

*Output:

5            Percentage used                                                 49 %

5            Percentage used                                                 48 %

5            Percentage used                                                 48 %*

It seems easy on paper, but it would great to automate in windows. I wish I could do this in Linux but need to run experiments on IOMeter and Windows.

I was thinking of setting up two scripts. One to run the loop on the command and out to a file. The second script would be the kill IOMeter. So the in the first script once keep running until it hit 90% and the call the second script to kill IOMeter.

Thank you in advance for the help and any pointers. I think I can get the kill part to work with some of the insight from this forum, but the loop and "watch" are elusive.

Comment: The first thing i feel I need to bring to your attention is that ,`3.` `Run command to retrieve (ie. ./smartmon getsmart all | Select-String -Pattern 'Percentage used')` seems to be using `powershell.exe` syntax, not `cmd.exe`. As this site is supposed to be assisting with a single reproducible issue with your code, you should ideally remove the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, and references to `cmd.exe`, and ask only about the code you've created. As it stands your question currently reads as an off topic code request.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I will make the changes and post the code which I created so far.

Comment: I have rolled back you edit, it was not what was asked, and created the same issue, the [[tag:cmd]] tag is for cmd.exe use, your code is for powershell.exe. You need to provide tags which match your code, preferably when you post it, not now before you have updated it.